# ERROR : POST http:/php/RelatorioFisico.php net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: php, angularjs

Alguém sabe porque está acontecendo esse erro quando eu vou fazer o download de uma planilha... Sendo que se eu atualizar a página o erro não volta a acontecer

#### Controller

```
$scope.GerarPlanilha = function (){
  $http({
              url: 'http:/php/RelatorioFisico.php',
              method: 'POST',
              responseType: 'arraybuffer',
              headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
              }
          }).success(function(data){
              var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
              saveAs(blob,'ContratosPendentes'+'.xlsx');
          }).error(function(){

          });
      };
```

Comment: acho que falta especificar o tamanho do arquivo..  `Content-Length`

Comment: no controller?? porque no headers do meu php eu fiz header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivo));